# Returning "-1" from int main shows "return value 4294967295" in the console why?

Tags: c, console-application, return-value, program-entry-point, negative-number

I am using Windows-11, 64-bit, and Dev-C++ (Bloodshed v5.11); the following is the simple code snippet:-

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    return -1;
}
```

I am getting the following output in the console:-

> ---
>
> ### Process exited after 0.2015 seconds with return value 4294967295
> Press any key to continue . . .

In the output, I do recognize that 4294967295 (2^32 - 1) is the max value of the unsigned 4-byte integer, but I cannot understand why this value is returned instead of "-1".

Comment: It's the *same* bit pattern `0xFFFFFFFF` (in 2's complement representation) and `unsigned` must be how the shell interprets it.

Comment: Hi, Weather Vane, Sorry but I do not understand what you tried to explain, can you elaborate or suggest some text to read, and why the question is closed ?

Comment: Everything in the computer is a number, and what that number means depends on context. The `0xFFFFFFFF` returned was `-1`  to the function that returned it, and `4294967295` to the function that received it, for some reason of the implementation. They are the same set of bits, treated in a different context.

Comment: This is a behavior of the console or command line program, not your program.

Comment: It is a mismatch between the C language specification and the [operating system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getexitcodeprocess).  Which uses DWORD for the exit status, an unsigned integer type.  No biggie, but it is best to reserve negative values for program aborts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-1` in two's complement signed number format (assuming 4 bytes long integers) is `0xffffffff` which is the maximum unsigned value that can be stored in the 4 bytes.  Two's complement format is used by almost all computers used nowadays (including your PC, Mac and any mobile phone)

Your shell is displaying the program return value as *unsigned integer*. The decimal representation of the `0xffffffff` hex number is `4294967295`

Comment: Not a 2's complement issue. -1 encode as a non-2's complement, when assigned to a 32-bit unsigned would still have the value 4294967295.  This is a _signed_ versus _unsigned_ type issue, not an encoding one.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica you assume that shell was written in C and it has assigned the variable. But if the language is not following the C rules or code in shell simple memcpy the return value. Then -1, if ones complement is used, will be 4294967294. You do not know what shell is doing with the return value. So I do not agree with your comment as it covers only one of many possibilities